# Laravel unable to update field to null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I can't figure out how to set a field to null on certain condition. It should be an easy query but I'n not able to set the right value for NULL on a nullable field.

```
        Product::where('id', $product_list)->update(['family_id' => null]);
```

nor

```
        Product::where('id', $product_list)->update(['family_id' => DB::raw(null)]);
```

did the trick.
Both cases compiled fine but the generated query seems to be wrong because I get a SQL error. In the irst case the error is :

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: update `products` set `family_id` = ?, `products`.`updated_at` = 2019-11-12 08:41:07 where `id` = ?)
```

and the error for the second one is :

```
QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', `products`.`updated_at` = ? where `id` = ?' at line 1 (SQL: update `products` set `family_id` = , `products`.`updated_at` = 2019-11-12 08:21:50 where `id` = ?)
```

In the first case it seems that NULL is not being added to the parameters to the prepared query, and in the secon the NULL value is being inserted as nothing in the query. There is any simple way to set the value to NULL?

Comment: What is the value of `$product_list`?

Comment: `dd($product_list)` let me know the output of this. And let me what you have passed as a parameter of this method.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider the following things first.

1) `family_id` column is nullable in your table. if not then set nullable.

2) Make sure you have in `$fillable` property of `Product` model column `family_id`.

Make sure `$product_list` returns `id` of that particular product.
if `$product_list` is collection/array of product data then use like:

```
Product::where('id', $product_list->id)->update(['family_id' => null]);
```

Comment: All points checked. $product_list has the right value(an integer).

Comment: working with models seems to be the solution. I was trying to avoid the unneccesary retrival of the record, but there in no other way:$product = Product::find($product_id);
$product->family_id = null;
$product->save();

Comment: @CarlosMora Ok, `Product::where('id', $product_id)->update(['family_id' => null]);`

Comment: No, the sentence you sugest is EXACTLY what I said as NOT WORKING in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Product::where('id', $product_list)->update(['family_id' => 'NULL']);

Comment: Doesn't works. Tries to assign the string 'NULL' -> SQL error. Tks!

Comment: Check the variable $product_list have the right value

May be something $product_list->id

Answer (score 0):

The `DB::raw()` requires a string of `'NULL'` to work properly:

```
Product::where('id', $product_list)->update(['family_id' => DB::raw('NULL')]);
```